# How to set binding in DataTemplate without knowing property name? DataGrid, DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a `DataTable` property in my viewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel()
{
    public MainViewModel() 
    {  PopulateDataTable(); }

    private DataTable employeeDataTable;
    public DataTable EmployeeDataTable
    {
        get { return employeeDataTable; }
        set
        {
            employeeDataTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeDataTable");
        }
    }

    private void PopulateDataTable()
    {            
        var _ds = new DataSet("Test");
        employeeDataTable = new DataTable();
        employeeDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {                        
                    theRow[j] = 1;
                }
                else
                    theRow[j] = false;
            }
            employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
        }
    }
}
```

I've created `DataTemplates` in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IntTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
           <Label Content="Integer"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WhatShouldIWriteHere?}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
           <Label Content="Boolean"/>
           <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=WhatShouldIWriteHere?}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Code-behind of the Window to use a necessary DataTemplate:

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = null;            

        switch (e.PropertyType.ToString())
        {
            case "System.Int32":
                dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["IntegerTemplate"];
                break;
            case "System.Boolean":
                dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["BooleanTemplate"];
                break;
        }
        if (dt != null)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn c = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dt,
                Header = e.Column.Header,
                HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
                HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
                SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName 
            };
            e.Column = c;
        }
    }
```

My question is what I should write in bindings of controls( `TextBlock` and `CheckBox`) of DataTemplates?

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IntTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
           <Label Content="Integer"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WhatShouldIWriteHere?}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
           <Label Content="Boolean"/>
           <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=WhatShouldIWriteHere?}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.X and upper only solution

Look at DLR [DynamicObject data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx), you can define own type inheriting from dynamic and bind to a property of that type, then in overriden [TryGetMembers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx) resolve requested data

your type should use (via aggregation) that DataTable instance

Comment: could you show some example of code in XAML? How should be it look like? Real code would be really useful.

Comment: Confirm you read MSDN about DynamicObject and how TryGetMembers works

Comment: I do not know `Name` of property, not the `Type` of property.